# Laravelでエラー（Class App\Http\Controllers\title does not exist）

Tags: laravel

Class App\Http\Controllers\title does not exist
とうエラーが出てしまいます。

考えられる原因はどちらになるのでしょうか？

Comment: 頂いた質問の情報ですと、原因判明するにはいささか難しく感じます。まずはエラーが発生しているのであれば他の人に再現が取れるような記述で書くと回答が得られやすいと思います。[良い質問をするには?](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)も参考にしてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

文字のタイプミス
useで宣言してない
ファイルをLaravelが認識してない
とそのエラーの文からは推測出来ます

Comment: ありがとうございます！
解決しました。 お礼のご返信遅くなりました。
(後日、どこが問題だったのか、こちらに記載いたします！）

Comment: 解決して何よりです